# How can I plot stacked bar plot for two columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to plot stacked bar plot for the table. The bars will represent the two columns of the dataframe, each showing the 'type' items stacked on top of each other.
[image]

I have tried doing this, but it's not working, I will appreciate any help

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
df.plot(x='type', y='0error_prone_nodes', kind='bar', stacked=True,ax=ax, position=0, width=0.4)
df.plot(x='type', y='0others', kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax, position=1, width=0.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'type': ['EDAC MCO', 'Hardware', 'LNet', 'Lustre'],
    'Oerror_prone_nodes': [3.529412, 34.117647, 15.294118, 3.529412],
    'Oothers': [0.000000, 1.369863, 2.283105, 5.936073]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('type', inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax)
plt.xlabel('Type')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.title('Stacked Bar Plot for Oerror_prone_nodes and Oothers')
plt.show()
```